# Apache Superset - Problem with CSV upload: FileNotFoundError

Tags: csv, upload, apache-superset

I've a problem in Apache Superset during the CSV upload. When i try to upload a CSV file, it return this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/pythonpath/app/static/uploads/tmpkvod0plb.csv'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/decorators.py", line 109, in wraps
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/views.py", line 94, in this_form_post
    response = self.form_post(form)
  File "/app/superset/views/database/views.py", line 141, in form_post
    delete=False,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 551, in NamedTemporaryFile
    (fd, name) = _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags, output_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 262, in _mkstemp_inner
    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0o600)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/superset/app/static/uploads/tmpt537yamb.csv'*
```

Comment: Can you provide further details? What have you tried since now?

Comment: I've installed superset with docker-compose. Once authenticated, i've tried to upload a CSV file

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very generic but without any other detail have a look at `/app/pythonpath/app/static/uploads` and:

- check directory existence
- check privileges
- check if that pathname is writable by the user running Apache Superset

If the directory does not exist, create it:

```
mkdir /app/pythonpath/app/static/uploads
```

Comment: The directory /app/pythonpath/app/static/uploads doesn't exists

Comment: Yep. Create it.

Comment: I don't have permission to create a folder in container. I've installed superset with docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem when trying to upload csv to mysql. I found the solution from that [issues](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/4287)

The reason is this running container does not have enough privilege. So you need to assign root to the superset when using docker-compose:

```
    env_file: docker/.env
    build: *superset-build
    container_name: superset_app
    command: ["flask", "run", "-p", "8088", "--with-threads", "--reload", "--debugger", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    user: root:root # add here
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes
```

Comment: isn't there a negative security implication when doing this?